# Contar números primos ordenar ascendente y descentente en python

Tags: python

Ayuda estoy aprendiendo a programar varias cosas no me imprime  la cantidad real de números primos y tampoco me ordena de manera ascendente otra cosa alguien me puede decir como realizar un función para imprimir la lista de forma descendente

```
lista = [453,650,981,762,547,320,9,1,123,543,76,900,1250,90,43,21]
def primo(num):
 numB=2
 res = 3
 while(numB<num):
  if num % numB==0 :
   return False

  else:
   res = True
   numB= numB+1


def ContarPrimos(lista):
 contador= 0 

while (contador<len(lista)-1):
 num = lista[contador]
  if primo(num)==True :
   print(num)

 contador = contador+1

 return contador

print("La cantidad de numeros primos es " +str(ContarPrimos(lista)))


def ascendente(lista):
 for i in range(1,len(lista)):
  for j in range(len(lista)-i):
   if lista[j]>lista[j+1]:
    x=lista[j]
    lista[j]=lista[j+1]
    lista[j+1]=x


    return lista

print("Numero ordenados de manera ascendente" +str(ascendente(lista)))
```

[image: Resultados]

---

[Link del codigo en repl.it](https://repl.it/GJzZ/7)

Comment: No necesitas escribir la función ascendente, python dispone de la función `sorted()` que precisamente ordena de manera ascendente, si deseas hacerlo descendente usa `sorted(reverse=True)`.

Answer (score 1):

Cuando avances en el aprendizaje de **Python** vas a ir viendo la gran cantidad de herramientas que tiene y siempre va a haber una forma más 
compacta y elegante de resolver un problema. Con tu ejemplo, se podría hacer esto:

```
lista = [453,650,981,762,547,320,9,1,123,543,76,900,1250,90,43,21]

def is_prime(n):
    return n > 1 and all(n % i for i in range(2, n))

print("Cantidad de primos   : {0}".format(sum(1 for n in lista if is_prime(n))))
print("Lista ordenada (asc) : {0}".format(sorted(lista)))
print("Lista ordenada (desc): {0}".format(sorted(lista,reverse=True)))
```

Hay algunas técnicas interesante del lenguaje:

1. Para calcular los primos, usamos la función `all` que evalúa todos los casos de un iterador que construimos dinámicamente y que representa todos los restos de de las sucesivas divisiones `n % i for i in range(2, n)`, por otro lado `range(2, n)` es un generador que devuelve números de 2 al número solicitado - 1.
2. Luego para calcular la cantidad calculamos la longitud (`len`) de una "comprensión de listas" `[n for n in lista if is_prime(n)]`que basicamente  representa todos los elementos de `lista`que sean primos
3. El uso de `sorted` es claro por si mismo.

Comment: Hay un pequeño error en el nombre de la función. Supongo que debería ser `is_prime`. Y una forma de no tener que crear una lista nueva para calcular el número de primos sería usando `sum()`: `sum(1 for n in lista if is_prime(n))`.

Comment: Me gustó lo del Sum, sin duda mucho más óptimo, lo voy a incorporar. Gracias..

Answer (score 0):

Hola espero esto te ayude a comprender lo que necesitas. si necesitas aprender mas sobre el lenguaje Python te invito a revisar su [documentación](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html) hay mucho que puedes aprender sobre el lenguaje.

La primer función determina si un número es primo, la segunda ya la tienes solo que para imprimir acendente o decendente cambiar en el if < o > a.

```
def es_primo(numero):
    divisores = 0 #cantidad de divisores de número.("contador")
    divisoresList = []#lista de números divisores de número
    for divisor in range(1, numero):#loop para recorrer hasta número
        if numero % divisor == 0 and divisor < numero:# si resto de número%divisor = 0 y divisor < número: ejecurar 
            divisores += 1#agregar +1 al contontador
            divisoresList.append(divisor)#agregar divisor a lista
    # si deceas conocer todos los números divisibles comenta las siguientes 2 lineas.
        if divisores > 2:# si divisor(contador) mayor a 2 el número no es primo. 
            break# salir del loop para evitar sobre carga.
    if divisores <= 1:
        print("número {} es primo".format(numero))
    else:
        print("número {} NO es primo".format(numero))
    print("número: ",numero)
    print("números divisores: ",divisoresList)
    print("___________________")

for i in range(1, 150):
    es_primo(i)

listaDeNumeros = [41,562,33,11,452,98,65,15,2,74,36,22]

def ordenar(lista):
    #metodo burbuja, para acendente o decendente cambiar el if < o >
    for x in range(1, len(lista)):
        for y in range(len(lista)-1):
            if lista[y] < lista[y+1]:
                aux = lista[y]
                lista[y] = lista[y+1]
                lista[y+1] = aux


print("lista sin ordenar\n",listaDeNumeros)
ordenar(listaDeNumeros)
print("Lista ordenada:\n",listaDeNumeros)
```